# Is there a fix for random crash to desktop?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I just updated my skyrim to the most recent version, and now I'm crashing to desktop randomly, with no error message. I disabled all my mods, even started a new game, still crashes. It doesn't crash anywhere specific, sometimes 5 minutes, sometimes 2 hours.
thanks.

Comment: drivers have been updated and skyrim was updated to most recent.. I'm turning off my AV just in case, I'm trying not to lower the graphics if I don't have to but that's the next step.

Answer (score 3):

For Skyrim, it tends to be RAM being overfilled, and crashing everything. You might want to lower your video settings, and update your graphic card drivers, just in case

Comment: even with the 4gb ram addon?

Comment: have you verified there was no update for the 4gb mod?

Comment: To see in-game how much VM you are using, try running Elys Meminfo, a SKSE plugin. I keep this running constantly. This way you can verify the game has allocated 4gb and you haven't exceeded it (though I find that hard to conceive).

Comment: Oh and also, the latest patch made 4gb Skyrim obsolete. You can stop using it.

Comment: From what I've been reading, many people are having issues with the patch itself... I never crashed before 1.3.10.. Maybe a fresh install is in order..

Answer (score 0):

I know when I played Battlefield 3 it was randomly crashing on me. Then I uninstalled AVG and it worked fine after that. Check to see if your anti virus is messing with it. Try turning that off and/or getting rid of it for a day.

Answer (score 0):

- patch Skyrim to the latest version
- upgrade video card drivers to latest stable version
- make sure your components are not overheating (if you're overclocking, tune down the overclock)